# How can I render normals in WebGL?

Tags: glsl, webgl

I am trying to render the normals as color values in WebGL. I have vertex normals for some surfaces and would like to color them with the normal values. I am currently doing this in the vertex shader:

```
void main(void) {
        gl_PointSize = aPointSize;
            gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        position_1 = gl_Position;
        vColor = aVertexColor;
        vIsDepth = aIsDepth;
        vIsNormal = aIsNormal;
        vHasTexture = aHasTexture;
        normals = uNMatrix*vec4(aNormal,1.0);
        if (aHasTexture > 0.5)
            vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;

    }
```

Fragment shader:

```
 if (vIsNormal > 0.5)
        {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(normals.xyz*0.5+0.5,1);

        }
    }
```

Right now my output is yellow for some reason. The r and g values are 127 and the b value is 0. Does anybody know what is going wrong? Is my method wrong in its basic understanding?

Comment: How does `uNMatrix` look? Kind of suspicious that you're using a 4x4 matrix for transforming normals. The normal matrix is normally 3x3. Can you see what happens if you pass the untransformed normal from the vertex shader to the fragment shader?

Comment: What @reto said, try changing `uNMatrix*vec4(aNormal,1.0);` to `uNMatrix*vec4(aNormal, 0.0);`  otherwise if there is any translation in `uNMatrix` it will mess up your normals.

Comment: `gl_FragColor = vec4(normals.xyz*0.5+vec3(0.5), 1.0);` ? You have vector and scalar addition, that may cause problems.

Comment: @AbstractAlgorithm Adding a scalar to a vector is perfectly valid and well defined in GLSL. It will add the scalar value to each vector component.

Comment: I tried without transforming the normals and also tried doing uNMatrix*vec4(aNormal,0.0). Both didn't work. I am stilll getting a grayscale image. The uNMatirx is obtained by doing transpose(inverse(uMVMatrix)). I also tried transpose(inverse(uPMatirx*uMVMatrix)). Both did not work. Since I have the normals only for vertex positions, is this kind of interpolation valid?